# An affine transformation of a plane onto another plane

Tags: analytic-geometry

How to write down the affine transformation that transforms the plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ onto the plane $z = 0$?

I cannot understand how to begin. I can express $z$ (if $C\neq 0$):
$$
z=-\frac{D+Ax+By}{C}
$$

And I need to get the plane $z = 0$. How to do this?

Comment: There are many such transformations, so you’ll have to narrow your question down with some more criteria. For example, do you want the transformation to be a rigid motion?

Comment: Yes, let it be a rigid motion.

Comment: OK. That’s narrows it down to an infinite number. It’s reasonable to assume that the mapping also preserves orientation, but that still leaves an infinite number of possible rotation/translation combinations.

Comment: I need some example of such a mapping. Any example suits me.

Comment: [Here’s one example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1956699/265466), which you could also have found by searching this site.